# MinGW-W64 Encoding with Clion

Tags: encoding, clion, mingw-w64

Windows 10 Jetbrains Clion 2018.2.1
MinGW-W64 Encoding

input[1] :

```
std::cout << "가나다라 abc" << std::endl;
```

output[1] :

```
媛?섎떎??abc
```

Settings > Editor > File Encodings
I can solve with Path setting: `EUC-KR`, but only configured file only. I have to configure Encoding setting every each project, every each file.

I found when using CMD, `chcp 65001` works, but clion's cpp output cannot manage like that.

VM option :

```
-Dconsole.encoding=EUC_KR
-Dconsole.encoding=EUC-KR
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF8
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=EUC_KR
-Dfile.encoding=EUC-KR
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I tried them all, each by each, but they does not work.

cygwin basically works well, but mingw-w64 doesn't work well. I searched for hours, but I couldn't find any answer.. :(

Thank you for reading..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Windows console only supports standard characters. If you try to print a special character, it will appear abnormally.

Windows cmd uses a simple ASCII table, while Windows uses an extended ANSI table. The 128 first characters are identical, so you can use them only.